# Words extraction

Tags: php, string, text-extraction

I've a txt file, structured like that:

```
*ABC123 a ABC123 ,
    / comment here
    DEF452 hju
then ABC123 h
   DEF452 hh,
   6HH , 7JJ , 8LL,
   Z123 enf of file
\ \

*ABC124 a ABC124 ,
    / comment here
    DEF4552 hju
then ABC124 h
   DEF4566 hh,
   62HH , 78JJ , 128LL,
   Z124 enf of file
\ \
```

What i need is to extract some pieces of this block of "code", that is variable in lenght and with different values each time.

Any tip?

Comment: Start by trying to extract it. Try *something*.

Comment: ie: i need all the variables after "then" , from  the first value to the end (the end of each block is delimited by " end of file \ \ "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/[a-z]+:\/\/\S+/', $string, $matches);
```

This is an easy way that'd work for a lot of cases, not all. All the matches are put in $matches.

Here is a link on using regular expressions in PHP: http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html. Also, here is a link for email regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Good luck.

Comment: thx i'll study on it :)